# Oracle 12C SQL - Populate missing results with Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, oracle12c

I have the following table of data (simplified for example)

```
TEAM    WORKS   TT
TEAM_A  JOB_1   10
TEAM_A  JOB_3   20
TEAM_B  JOB_2   30
```

And i wish to get the following results

```
TEAM    WORKS   TT
TEAM_A  JOB_1   10
TEAM_A  JOB_2   NULL
TEAM_A  JOB_3   20
TEAM_B  JOB_1   NULL
TEAM_B  JOB_2   30
TEAM_B  JOB_3   NULL
```

This results table needs to add in, for each team, the type of work that does not appear in the original data set, and give the time value `NULL`

I have got the following SQL as an attempt and have tried many join types, but can never get my desired results.

```
WITH BASE AS (
            SELECT 'TEAM_A' AS TEAM, 'JOB_1' AS WORKS, 10 AS TT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL   SELECT 'TEAM_A' AS TEAM, 'JOB_3' AS WORKS, 20 AS TT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL   SELECT 'TEAM_B' AS TEAM, 'JOB_2' AS WORKS, 30 AS TT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
        BASE.TEAM
    ,   BASE.WORKS
    ,   BASE.TT
FROM BASE
FULL OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT 'JOB_1' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'JOB_2' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'JOB_3' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
) WORK_TYPES ON BASE.WORKS = WORK_TYPES.WORKS
;
```

Comment: cross join team and work values. Outer join.

Comment: jarlh, do you have an example? when i cross join, it still gives me incorrect results.

Comment: `partitioned outer join` was created exactly for such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross join the distinct teams and works, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select te.team, wo.work, ta.tt
from (select distinct team from mytable) te
cross join (select distinct work from mytable) wo
left join mytable ta
    on ta.team = te.team and ta.work = wo.work
order by te.team, wo.work
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to use `partitioned outer join`, that is exactly for such problems as yours one:

```sql
WITH BASE AS (
            SELECT 'TEAM_A' AS TEAM, 'JOB_1' AS WORKS, 10 AS TT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL   SELECT 'TEAM_A' AS TEAM, 'JOB_3' AS WORKS, 20 AS TT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL   SELECT 'TEAM_B' AS TEAM, 'JOB_2' AS WORKS, 30 AS TT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
        BASE.TEAM
    ,   WORK_TYPES.WORKS
    ,   BASE.TT
FROM (
                      SELECT 'JOB_1' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL   SELECT 'JOB_2' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL   SELECT 'JOB_3' AS WORKS FROM DUAL
     ) WORK_TYPES 
     left JOIN BASE
     partition by (base.team)
     ON BASE.WORKS = WORK_TYPES.WORKS
;
```

Result:

```
TEAM   WORKS         TT
------ ----- ----------
TEAM_A JOB_1         10
TEAM_A JOB_2
TEAM_A JOB_3         20
TEAM_B JOB_1
TEAM_B JOB_2         30
TEAM_B JOB_3
```